# How to use the Search box on these Stack Exchange sites with the Galaxy S?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, browser, search, input-methods

When I type something into the search box at the top right of the main page, I get a *Next* key instead of the *Go* or enter key.  If I enter text in search, pressing *Next* takes me to the interesting tags input, then to the ignored tags input; pressing *Go* from there takes me back to the main page, with my search text sitting in the search box and no way to do anything with it!

My phone is a Galaxy S and I've tried all three of the input methods -- Swype, Samsung and Android -- and all behave the same way.

From https://android.stackexchange.com/search (it's the same text on other SE sites):

> To search, type in the box at the top right of every page and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

How can I provide the Enter that the search functionality depends on?  If I can't do it directly, are there any workarounds?

(I'm certain I've run into this problem on other websites too, but I can't think where right now.)

Comment: Works for me on HTC Desire... must be a problem specific to your phone.

Comment: @Mark: I wondered why nobody else had noticed it before now. :)

Comment: @Niall: I Uber Keyboard on my Moto Droid, and I also tried the stock keyboard and on both I'm given the option to "Go" in the SE search field.

Comment: That's odd, I can confirm I'm seeing the same thing on my Vodafone UK Galaxy S (Eclair 2.1 update 1, build JM4). I don't actually search much on StackExchange sites, I'm more of a browser so never noticed before. On the full /search page the only box that's gives me a "Go" button is the DuckDuckGo box.

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: @Michael: the default one on the phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't if there's something on the StackExchange sites that has changed, or if the Froyo update has fixed this, but I do get the <kbd>Go</kbd> button now, not a <kbd>Next</kbd> button when I type into this site's search box on my phone.

*(Vodafone UK branded official Samsung Galaxy S 2.2 Froyo release JP7)*

Comment: I'm still seeing `Next` on 2.1, so it's probably the 2.2 update.  I'll confirm if and when T-Mobile USA gets around to releasing it to their customers.

Comment: Even with my hardware keyboard on my Moto Flipside (2.1) pressing the return key doesn't work. :-(

Comment: Oops, I completely forgot about this question.  It works now and I'm pretty sure it was after I installed the Froyo update.